# PHP Get Cookie by Session ID (or otherwise pass data between two different connections)

Tags: php, session, cookies, apache2, wkhtmltopdf

Normally I try to format my question as a basic question and then explain my situation, but the solution I'm looking for might be the wrong one altogether, so here's the problem:

I'm building a catalog application for an auction website that has the ability to save individual lots. So far this has worked great by simply creating a cookie with a comma-separated list of IDs for those lots, via something like this:

```
$_COOKIE["MyLots_$AuctionId"] = implode(",",$arrayOfIds);
```

The problem I'm now hitting is that when I go to print the lots, I'm using wkhtmltopdf through the command-line to request the url of the printout I want, like this:

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf '$urlofmylots' filename.pdf");
```

The problem is that I can't pass a cookie to this call, because Apache sees an internal request, not the request of the user. I tried putting it in the get string, but once I have more than a pre-set limit for GET parameters, that value disappears from the $_GET array on the target url. I can't seem to find a way to send POST data between them. My next possible ideas are the following:

1. Maybe just pass the sessionID to the url, and see if there's a way that I can use PHP to dig through the cookies for that session and pull the right cookie, but that sounds like it'd be risky security-wise for a PHP server to allow (letting one session be aware of another). Example:

   ```
   exec("wkhtmltopdf '$urlofmylots?sessionId=$sessionIdFromThisRequest' filename.pdf");
   ```
2. Possibly set a session variable and then pass that session Id, and see if I can use PHP to wade through that information instead (rather than using the cookie).
3. Would I be able to just create an array and somehow have that other script be aware of it, possibly by including it? That doesn't really solve the problem of wkhtmltopdf expecting a web-facing address as its first parameter.
4. (not really an idea, but some reasoning) In other instances of using this, I've just passed an ID to the script that generates the markup for wkhtmltopdf to parse, and the script uses that ID to get data from the database. I don't want to store this data in a file or the database for the simple purpose of transferring data from the caller to the callee in this case. Cookies and sessions seem cleaner since apache/php handle memory allocation for these sessions.

The ultimate problem here is that I'm trying to get my second script (referenced here by $urlofmylots) to be aware of data available to the calling script but it's being executed as if it were an external web request, not two php scripts being called from the web root.

Can anyone offer some insight here?

Comment: You seem to be a little confused about the behaviour of Apache vs PHP. It is PHP that handles all the session-related information - cookies, data files, session IDs etc are all internal to PHP and separate from Apache. Apache handles the application layer network traffic (the HTTP request/response receiving/sending) and hands off everything related to the content and value handling to PHP. I know this doesn't really help you, but you mention Apache regularly in inappropriate places in the question and it makes it more confusing.

Comment: Ha! While that doesn't really help me, I see your point, and I was confused about what I was trying to say. Let me go back and edit it to clarify.

Comment: I've edited it to clarify what I meant to say. Let me know if this is more clear.

Comment: So for clarity, when you say "save individual lots", this is for example a client adding to a list of favourites? An auction site will already be using a database, is there a reason not to save the saved lots there? (it will probably be easier to manage expired lots like this for example). It would be relatively simple to have an internal page where you call `lotsForUser.php?userId=123`, and this would enumerate the lots from the database. Also, this would save lots between sessions, and they dont lose data if they clear their cookies.

Comment: @leigh I totally understand your logic, but this site does not have a user login. It's just a showcase for the lots available, the users actually go to a DIFFERENT site to log in and bid on the lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider rendering whatever the output of `$urlofmylots?lots=$lots_to_print` would be to a temporary file and running `wkhtmltopdf` against that file.

Comment: I didn't realize I could use a local html file path. I'm going to try this, as it would also add the benefit of eliminating a server request.

Comment: If you want to easily capture the output of your script to a file, from within PHP itself, check out [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). `ob_start()` will start capturing output, `$output = ob_get_clean()` will take everything that was going to be sent to the browser and store it in a variable. Then do what you want with the variable.

Comment: As it turns out, I'm using a class to build all my html and then echoing it all at once, so it should be relatively easy to just write that to a file rather than echo it. Why I didn't think of this before I have no clue. That's why I love SO.

Comment: This ended up solving the problem, but it lets me know I probably need to re-architect this application as the specs are very different from when we started.